# python ssh script error

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-keys

Just a bit of background, I'm writing a script to ssh to several remote servers and copy my public key to them.  I embarked on writing a custon ssh client because I can't install any of the external python modules.  To make a long story short, the company I work for says, if it isn't part of the standard python library, you can't use it.

After weeks of searching I found a script that I thought was the answer to all of my prayers.  I've modified it to suit my needs but I'm getting a variable not found error and I need a little guidance in figuring it out.

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pty, re, os, sys, stat, socket
from getpass import getpass

class ssherror(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

class sshclient:
    def __init__(self, ip, passwd, user, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.user = user
        self.port = port

    def runcmd(self, c):
        (pid, f) = pyt.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            os.execlp("ssh", "ssh", '-p %d' % self.port, self.user + '@' + self.ip, c)
        else:
        return (pid, f)

    def pushfile(self, src, dst):
        (pid, f) = pty.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            os.execlp("scp", "scp", '-P %d' % self.port, src, self.user + '@' + self.ip + ':' + dst)
        else:
            return (pid, f)

    def pushdir(self, src, dst):
        (pid, f) = pty.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            os.execlp("scp", "scp", '-P %d' % self.port, "-r", src, self.user + '@' + self.ip + ':' + dst)
        else:
            return (pid, f)

    def _read(self, f):
        x = ''
        try:
            x = os.read(f, 1024)
        except Exception, e:
            pass
        return x

    def connect(self, pid, f):
        output = ''
        got = self._read(f)
        m = re.search('authenticity of host', got)
        if m:
            os.write(f, 'yes\n')
            while True:
                got = self._read(f)
                m = re.search('Permanently added', got)
                if m:
                    break

            got = self._read(f)
        m = re.search('assword:', got)
        if m:
            os.write(f, self.passwd + '\n')
            tmp = self._read(f)
            tmp += self._read(f)
            m = re.search('Permission denied', tmp)
            if m:
                raise Exception('Invalid passwd')
            got = tmp
        while got and len(got) > 0:
            output += got
            got = self._read(f)
        os.waitpid(pid, 0)
        os.close(f)
        return output

    def cmd(self, c):
        (pid, f) = self.runcmd(c)
        return self.connect(pid, f)

    def push(self, src, dst):
        s = os.stat(src)
        if stat.S_ISDIR(s[stat.ST_MODE]):
            (pid, f) = self.pushdir(src, dst)
        else:
            (pid, f) = self.pushfile(src, dst)
        return self.connect(pid, f)



def sshconnect(ip, passwd, user, port=22):
    s = sshclient(ip, passwd, user, port)
    return s.connect(pid, f)


def sshpush(ip, passwd, src, dst, user, port=22):
    s = sshclient(ip, passwd, user, port)
    return s.push(src, dst)



passwd = getpass()
src = '/path/to/dir/being/copied'
dst = '/path/to/destination/directory'
user = os.getlogin()
port = portnum
hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
for host in hosts:
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()

    print 'Socket Created'
    try:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
    except socket.gaierror:
        print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting...'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Ip address of ' + host + ' is ' + ip
    sshconnect(ip, passwd, user, port)
    sshpush(ip, passwd, src, dst, user, port=22)
    print 'ssh directory copied to ' + host
```

I've made quite a few changes to it but I'm still getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh.py", line 129, in <module>
    sshconnect(ip, passwd, user, port)
  File "ssh.py", line 99, in sshconnect
    return s.connect(pid, f)
NameError: global name 'pid' is not defined
```

I know I need to define the pid, but I'm drawing a blank on the best way to go about doing it.  Any assistance, suggestions, Advil would be most sincerely appreciated!!!

Comment: Seriously. What kind of company is that? One of the greatest advantages of Python is the enormous number of packages available.

Comment: You have no var named pid declared, neither inside the function, as an argument, or a global. Since I don't fully understand the reason of such a structure, I can not help you further.

Comment: RickyA - don't get me started! LOL I've made the same argument to them until I'm blue in the face but when you have non-technical people making technical decisions, you get into these type situations.....

Comment: Yn5an3 - I know pid isn't defined.  I wanted to get insight on the best way to define it.  I got the original script from Paul Mikesell's blog because it fits my needs perfectly if I could ever get it to work....

Answer (score 1):

Typos on line:

20: `(pid, f) = pyt.fork()` (should be pty)

24: nothing after `else:`

93: `pid` and `f` are not defined in this function scope -> this is your problem.

106: `portnum` is not known in this scope

Do they allow you to use an [proper](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) IDE with code validation? Switch to it. 
Otherwise if you like it barebone vi go for an static source [checker](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/pythonmagazine/completely-different/2008-03-linters/index.html).

Looking at the code snippet from Paul Mikesell I think you don't need your `sshconnect` function at line 91. Just make a call to `sshclient.push` like you do in your next function (`sshpush`) and it will connect for itself.

Comment: Got it. Got it. Drat! I know I need to define them, I just need to figure out how.  portnum isn't an actual value, I just used it as a spacer. And I do have IBM RSA for WebSphere....